# Auto create next Key in python dictionary

Tags: python

Is there an easy way to create dictionary like associative array in php? in php i can do:

```
> $x='a';
> while($x<d){
>     $arr[]['Letter']=$x;
>      $x++
>     }
```

The interpreter adds automatically a new number into empty brackets "[]"
so i can access letter `b` from `$arr[1]['Letter']`, etc.

Is there a way to do same with python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I'm stupid. Of course there is a way of doing this in Python. Like so:

```
result = [{'Letter': chr(i+97)} for i in range(26)]
```

That will give you a List. Which can be indexed with a number.
So `result[1]['Letter']` will give you `'b'`.

Answer (score 3):

Empty-brackets indexing is syntactically invalid in Python, but you could conceivably program a class that takes e.g. `[None]` as a signal to add one more key with a dict as its value and an incremented integer as the key.  Before I make the substantial effort to program such a class, I'd love to understand what real problem you're trying to solve that, e.g. a `collections.defaultdict` wouldn't address.

Comment: As a temporary solution i used defaultdict.

Answer (score 2):

In python lists and dictionaries are distinct types.  PHP has the one type to rule them all the associative array.

I think what you want to do above translates into a list of dictionaries in python, like this

```
x = [ dict(Letter=chr(i)) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('f')) ]
```

If you try this in the interpreter

```
>>> x = [ dict(Letter=chr(i)) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('f')) ]
>>> x
[{'Letter': 'a'}, {'Letter': 'b'}, {'Letter': 'c'}, {'Letter': 'd'}, {'Letter': 'e'}]
>>> x[0]
{'Letter': 'a'}
>>> x[1]
{'Letter': 'b'}
>>> x[1]['Letter']
'b'
>>>
```

Or if you prefer it written out in full without a list comprehension

```
x = []
for c in range(ord('a'),ord('f')):
    d = { 'Letter': chr(c) }
    x.append(d)
```

Comment: I think you're the first one here who got what the OP was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Already mentioned that Python doesn't support it by default.

You can achieve that effect by using the length of the dictionary, like this:

```
>>> arr = {'letter':{1:'a'}}
>>> arr
{'letter': {1: 'a'}}
>>> arr['letter'][len(arr['letter'])+1] = 'b'
>>> arr['letter'][len(arr['letter'])+1] = 'c'
>>> arr['letter'][len(arr['letter'])+1] = 'd'
>>> arr
{'letter': {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}}
>>>
```